# ACF Map not showing up

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I am developing my first wordpress template with ACF's Map, but the div with the code is always coming out empty.

Could anyone bring me some light, please? I know it is very possibly something very stupid that I have missed out, but I am new to PHP and am working hard to learn :)

This is my index code, I had to remove the LOOP as it was giving me an error.

I got this code from [ACF's website](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/google-map/)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


<div class="map">
<?php if( have_rows('address') ): ?>
    <div class="acf-map">
        <?php while ( have_rows('address') ) : the_row(); 

            $location = get_sub_field('address');

            ?>
            <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>">
                <h4><?php the_sub_field('room_type'); ?></h4>
                <p class="address"><?php echo $location['address']; ?></p>
                <p><?php the_sub_field('description'); ?></p>
            </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is my header code, I have simply copied from ACF.

```
<style type="text/css">

.acf-map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    border: #ccc solid 1px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

/*
*  render_map
*
*  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $el (jQuery element)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function render_map( $el ) {

    // var
    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

    // vars
    var args = {
        zoom        : 16,
        center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // create map               
    var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);

    // add a markers reference
    map.markers = [];

    // add markers
    $markers.each(function(){

        add_marker( $(this), map );

    });

    // center map
    center_map( map );

}

/*
*  add_marker
*
*  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $marker (jQuery element)
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

    // var
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

    // create marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position    : latlng,
        map         : map
    });

    // add to array
    map.markers.push( marker );

    // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if( $marker.html() )
    {
        // create info window
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content     : $marker.html()
        });

        // show info window when marker is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            infowindow.open( map, marker );

        });
    }

}

/*
*  center_map
*
*  This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function center_map( map ) {

    // vars
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // loop through all markers and create bounds
    $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

        bounds.extend( latlng );

    });

    // only 1 marker?
    if( map.markers.length == 1 )
    {
        // set center of map
        map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
        map.setZoom( 16 );
    }
    else
    {
        // fit to bounds
        map.fitBounds( bounds );
    }

}

/*
*  document ready
*
*  This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded)
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   5.0.0
*
*  @param   n/a
*  @return  n/a
*/

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.acf-map').each(function(){

        render_map( $(this) );

    });

});

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: What's the error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

1.- Make sure jQuery is loading first. You said the code is in the header so check if jQuery is loading in the footer and let us know what's the error you have in the console.

2.- var_dump($location) and make sure your field is address on ACF. See if you have the data there...